# How to get the text from a select field in an form with Cakephp and JsHelper

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $this->Js->get('#PoolsOptionPoolId')->event(
        'change',
        $this->Js->request(
            array(
                'controller'=>'candidates',
                'action'=>'getByType'
            ),
            array(
                'update'=>'#PoolsOptionCandidateId',
                'async' => true,
                'method' => 'post',
                'dataExpression'=>true,
                'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(
                    array(
                        'isForm' => true,
                        'inline' => true
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

I'm using the JsHelper from cakephp to atualize a select field dynamically and I need to pass the text value from a selected option of the select field from my form to the controller. Well this function works fine if I need to pass the value from the selected option, but for my case I need pass the text. So, is it possible to put some argument in the serializeForm function to pass the text and not the value of the selected option?

Thanks
Pablo

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but I would recommend just not using JsHelper at all.  I've always found it more complicated and often doesn't work like you want it to.  It's deprecated in CakePHP 3 because of this, I believe - it's just not any easier to hide it behind another layer of complication.

**Answer:**  Just use standard JavaScript (or jQuery), not CakePHP's JsHelper